# Android 2.3: Dos botones en Listview con BaseAdapter y OnClickListener

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

**MI CASO:**

1. Tengo un fragment (fraArticulos) y su respectivo Layout (lytarticulos) el cual contiene un listview (lstArticulos).

   **fraArticulos.java**

   ```
   public class fraArticulos extends Fragment {  
       String[] NomProd = {'PC','Teclado','Mouse'};  
       String[] DescProd= {'CPU I7','Kit MS','6 botones'};    
       String[] PrecProd= {'2000.00','80.00','60.00'};    
       String[] StockProd= {'10','50','100'};  

       clsAdapArticulos Adapter;  
       ListView miLista;  

       @Override  
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
       View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.lytArticulos, container, false);  
       miLista = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lstArticulos);  
       Adapter = new clsAdapArticulos(getActivity(), NomProd, DescProd, PrecProd, StockProd);  
       miLista.setAdapter(Adapter);  

       miLista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  
           @Override  
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {  
               // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"item: "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
           }  
       });  
       return view;  
       }  
   }
   ```

**lytarticulos.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnr1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="105dp">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstArticulos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:clickable="true">


    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

2. El listview (lstArticulos) es personalizado a través otro layout (itemarticulo) el cual tiene 02 ImageButton (btnDetalles y btnElegir).

**itemarticulo**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/box_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/single_post_circuito_linearbox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.7">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="NomProd"
                    android:id="@+id/lblNP"
                />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="Desc Prod"
                    android:id="@+id/lblDesc"
                />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Precio  prod"
                    android:id="@+id/lblPrec"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Stock  prod"
                    android:id="@+id/lblStk"
                >
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="46dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnDetalles"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/deta" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnElegir"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/eleg" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

3. Estoy usando un BaseAdapter para rellenar la lista (clsAdapArticulos).
   **clsAdapArticulos.java**

   ```
   public class clsAdapArticulos extends BaseAdapter {
       // Declare Variables
       Context context;
       String[] NombreProds;
       String[] DescProds;
       String[] PrecioProds;
       String[] StockProds;
       LayoutInflater inflater;  

       public clsAdapArticulos(Context context,
                          String[] cNombreProds,
                          String[] cDescProds ,
                          String[] cPrecioProds,
                          String[] cStockProds) {
           this.context = context;
           this.NombreProds = cNombreProds;
           this.DescProds = cDescProds;
           this.PrecioProds = cPrecioProds;
           this.StockProds = cStockProds;
       }  

       @Override
       public int getCount() {
           return NombreProds.length;
       }

       @Override
       public Object getItem(int position) {
           return null;
       }  

       @Override
       public long getItemId(int position) {
           return 0;
       }  

       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  

           TextView xNombreProds;
           TextView xDescProds;
           TextView xPrecioProds;
           TextView xStockProds;
           ImageButton xbDetal,xbElegi;

           inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

           View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemarticulo, parent, false);

           xNombreProds = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblNP);
           xDescProds = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblDesc);
           xPrecioProds = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblPrec);
           xStockProds = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblStk);

           xNombreProds.setText(NombreProds[position]);
           xDescProds.setText(DescProds[position]);
           xPrecioProds.setText(PrecioProds[position]);
           xStockProds.setText(StockProds[position]);

           xbDetal = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDetalles);
           xbDetal.setTag(position);
           xbElegi = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnElegir);
           xbElegi.setTag(position);

           xbDetal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   // Toast.makeText(context,"presionó detalles",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
               }
           });  

           xbElegi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   // Toast.makeText(context,"presionó elegir",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
               }
           });
           return itemView;
       }  
   }
   ```

**LO QUE FUNCIONA:**

1. El adapter rellena el listview correctamente.
2. El Adapter tiene un clicklistener para cada botón y funciona correctamente mostrando un toast (esto es facil de hacerlo).
3. En el fragment despues del setAdapter, el OnItemClick funciona correctamente cuando presiono un elemento de la lista mostrandome otro Toast con la posicion del item (esto también es fácil).

**LO QUE QUIERO Y NO LOGRO HACERLO:**

1. Quitar el toast del OnClickListener de los botones en el Adpater (ya lo hice).
2. Cuando presione cualquiera de los botones me muestre la posición del elemento, para según eso realizar una acción diferente (esta programación se debe hacer en el fragment y no en el adapter; el problema no sé como ni en que parte debo hacerlo).

Ayuda, llevo 5 dias buscando la solución pero no he logrado solucionarlo.

**ACLARACIÓN:**

> Me he leído casi todos los artículos existentes pero ninguno me ha solucionado el problema. La razón es que muchos de ellos son "copy
>   paste" de otros y no están bien explicados.

Comment: Se que es mucho pedir pero si podrían ser precisos en su explicación al menos la ubicación donde debe ir el código que necesite implementar. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: podrias poner algo de tu codigo para detectar bien el problema?

Comment: Alguna porción de codigo?

Comment: Ya puse todo el código (lo que me costo ponerlo jejeje), Ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por fin he podido dar con la respuesta, espero les sirva a otros:
1. En el Adapter (clsAdapArticulos)

**ANTES**

```
        xbDetal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Toast.makeText(context,"presionó detalles",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });  

        xbElegi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Toast.makeText(context,"presionó elegir",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });
```

**DESPUES**

```
        xbDetal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(view, position, 0);
            }
        });  

        xbElegi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(view, position, 0);
            }
        });
```

2. En el fragment.

**ANTES**

```
    miLista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {  
            // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"item: "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
        }  
    });
```

**DESPUES**

```
    miLista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {  
            int viewId = view.getId();
            switch (viewId){
                  case R.id.btnDetalles:
                       //Boton Detalles
                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Boton detalles: "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);                         
                       break;
                  case R.id.btnElegir:
                       //boton Elegir
                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Boton elegir: "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                       break;
                  default:
                       //item de la lista
                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Item lista: "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                       break;
            }
        }  
    });
```

Comment: Por cierto lo saqué de este esta respuesta en este post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27595251/7705459

Comment: De acuerdo, siento no haberte podido responder antes. Saludos y hasta la proxima.

Answer (score 1):

lo puedes hacer con un listener creado por ti mismo. Por ejemplo tienes este listener:

```
public interface OnItemActionClickListener(){
     void onDetalleClick();
     void onElegirClick();
}
```

Luego tu fragment haces que implemente esta interface:

```
public class fraArticulos extends Fragment implements OnItemActionClickListener{
...

@Override
public void onDetalleClick(){
    //Tu codigo...
}

@Override
public void onElegirClick(){
    //Tu codigo...
}

...

}
```

Y en la construcción del adapter le pasas una referencia a este listener que será el mismo fragment dado que lo implementa:

```
Adapter = new clsAdapArticulos(getActivity(), NomProd, DescProd, PrecProd, StockProd, this);  
miLista.setAdapter(Adapter);
```

Luego en el constructor del adapter:

```
public class clsAdapArticulos extends BaseAdapter {
    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    String[] NombreProds;
    String[] DescProds;
    String[] PrecioProds;
    String[] StockProds;
    LayoutInflater inflater; 

    OnItemActionClickListener listener; 

    public clsAdapArticulos(Context context,
                       String[] cNombreProds,
                       String[] cDescProds ,
                       String[] cPrecioProds,
                       String[] cStockProds,
                       OnItemActionClickListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.NombreProds = cNombreProds;
        this.DescProds = cDescProds;
        this.PrecioProds = cPrecioProds;
        this.StockProds = cStockProds;
        this.listener = listener;
    } 
...
```

Para terminar en tu adapter tan solo tienes que llamar al evento que quieras del listener recien implementado:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  

        ...

        xbDetal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onDetalleClick();
            }
        });  

        xbElegi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onElegirClick();
            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }
```

Espero que ahora si lo entiendas y lo puedas implementar.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, pero ya habia logrado solucionarlo minutos antes, ahi dejo la solución.